# Why my filed component is not removing dynamically in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to add textfield and combobox dynamically on button click but not able to do it. Below is the code which I tried. In this code I have added the field successfully but not able to remove the item one by one on button click. only last item is removing after adding the field multiple times. so please check my code where I did mistake.

```
package application;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region.Margins;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class CustomerController  implements Initializable {

    public JFXTextField 
    acc_no,ifsc_code,micr_code,acc_no1,ifsc_code1,micr_code1;
    public JFXComboBox<String> bank_name,bank_name1;
    public JFXButton add_row,rmv_row;
    public GridPane grid_component;
    public VBox vBox2_component, vbox1_component;

    public AnchorPane anchor_pane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bank_name.getItems().removeAll(bank_name.getItems());
        bank_name.getItems().addAll("Bank of India", "Dena Bank", "HDFC Bank");
         new AutoCompleteComboBoxListener(bank_name);

    }

// add button functionality

    public void AddBankDetails(ActionEvent event) {
        /*if(count == max_row-1){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText("Maximum of 10 rows can be added\",\"Failed!!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

         count++;*/

        bank_name1 = new  JFXComboBox();
        bank_name1.getStyleClass().add("textfield_margin");
        bank_name1.setLabelFloat(true);
        bank_name1.setFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("#2196F3"));
        bank_name1.setPromptText("Bank Name");
        bank_name1.setUnFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("939393"));
        vbox1_component.setMargin(bank_name1, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));

        ifsc_code1 = new JFXTextField();
        ifsc_code1.getStyleClass().add("textfield_margin");
        ifsc_code1.setLabelFloat(true);
        ifsc_code1.setFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("#2196F3"));
        ifsc_code1.setPromptText("IFSC Code");
        ifsc_code1.setUnFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("939393"));
        vbox1_component.setMargin(ifsc_code1, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));

         acc_no1 = new JFXTextField();
        acc_no1.getStyleClass().add("textfield_margin");
        acc_no1.setLabelFloat(true);
        acc_no1.setFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("#2196F3"));
        acc_no1.setPromptText("Account number");
        acc_no1.setUnFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("939393"));
        vBox2_component.setMargin(acc_no1, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));

         micr_code1 = new JFXTextField();
        micr_code1.getStyleClass().add("textfield_margin");
        micr_code1.setLabelFloat(true);
        micr_code1.setFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("#2196F3"));
        micr_code1.setPromptText("MICR Code");
        micr_code1.setUnFocusColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("939393"));
        vBox2_component.setMargin(micr_code1, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
        vbox1_component.getChildren().addAll(bank_name1,ifsc_code1);
        vBox2_component.getChildren().addAll(acc_no1,micr_code1);
    }

  //remove button functionality

    public void rmvBankDetails(ActionEvent events) {

        vbox1_component.getChildren().removeAll(bank_name1,ifsc_code1);
        vBox2_component.getChildren().removeAll(acc_no1,micr_code1);

    }

}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: in each add you overwrite the fields' values with the newly added controls - that's exactly one per field. In remove you remove those last added controls.

Answer (score 0):

You only store a reference to the controls that are created for the last call of `AddBankDetails`. This means if you click the add button multiple times and then click the remove button multiple times. You only get a single successful remove operation for the `VBox`es.

Assuming this is the only code modifying the `VBox`es and the `VBox`es don't contain other children, you could simply remove the last 2 children from each list:

```
private static void removeElements(List<?> list, int count) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size >= count) {
        list.subList(size - count, size).clear();
    }
}
```

```
public void rmvBankDetails(ActionEvent events) {
    removeElements(vbox1_component.getChildren(), 2);
    removeElements(vBox2_component.getChildren(), 2);
}
```

#### Additional notes:

- Depending on your layout using `GridPane` could be a option. `TableView` may also be worth a look.
- You probably need access to all your controls, so keeping a list of the newly added controls in a list could be desireable. Using this data you could also retrieve the controls to remove.

  ```
  private static class Container {
      final JFXComboBox bank_name1;
      final JFXTextField ifsc_code1;
      final JFXTextField acc_no1;
      final JFXTextField micr_code1;

      Container(JFXComboBox bank_name1, JFXTextField ifsc_code1, JFXTextField acc_no1, JFXTextField micr_code1) {
          this.bank_name1 = bank_name1;
          this.ifsc_code1 = ifsc_code1;
          this.acc_no1 = acc_no1;
          this.micr_code1 = micr_code1;
      }

  }

  private final List<Container> bankDetailsContainers = new ArrayList<>();

  public void AddBankDetails(ActionEvent event) {
      ...
      bankDetailsContainers.add(new Container(bank_name1, ifsc_code1, acc_no1, micr_code1));
  }

  public void rmvBankDetails(ActionEvent events) {
      if (!bankDetailsContainers.isEmpty()) {
          Container c = bankDetailsContainers.remove(bankDetailsContainers.size() - 1);
          vbox1_component.getChildren().removeAll(c.bank_name1, c.ifsc_code1);
          vBox2_component.getChildren().removeAll(c.acc_no1, c.micr_code1);
      }

  }
  ```